# WebGl will not work in Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, webgl

Whenever I try and go to a site that utilizes WebGl, it never loads. I'm using a mid '09 MacBook Pro (10.7.5), and running Chrome 33.0.1750.117. Is there a setting that I need to turn on in Chrome somewhere to get everything to work?

Comment: What do you get by visiting http://get.webgl.com ?

Comment: "Hmm. While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable. If possible, please ensure that you are running the latest drivers for your video card."

I tried in Firefox, and works perfectly.

Comment: what does it say if you go to `about:gpu`?

Comment: Look for WebGL in chrome://flags/ -- is it enabled?

Comment: It is enabled in chrome://flags but when I go to chrome://gpu I get this WebGL: "Unavailable. Hardware acceleration disabled"

Comment: Probably blacklisted. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=233523). You can override this with the ignore-gpu-blacklist flag in chrome://flags

Comment: This is odd. Isn't Chrome supposed to use the SwiftShader software rasterizer for black-listed GPUs? http://blog.chromium.org/2012/02/gpu-accelerating-2d-canvas-and-enabling.html

Comment: It seems Chrome's software rasterizer isn't available for Mac: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=127813

Answer (score 6):

Several bugs in Mac OpenGL drivers have been discovered by the WebGL team at Google. Apple fixes the bugs but the fixes are generally only available in the latest version of the OS AFAIK :(

If the Chrome team decides the bugs are a security issue or if they affect WebGL compatibility in too many cases they have to blacklist that GPU on versions of the OS that still have the bug. I'm not saying upgrading to 10.9 is guaranteed to fix the issue.

For example: *WebGL is buggy with the NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, 9400, and 9400M on MacOSX earlier than 10.8* from http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/gpu/config/software_rendering_list_json.cc

You can work around this by launching chrome with `--ignore-gpu-blacklist` as in open a terminal and with chrome **not** already running and type

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --ignore-gpu-blacklist
```

Or by enabling *Override software rendering list* in `about:flags`. Of course they are blacklisted for a reason ;)

Comment: Very informative answer. BTW, do you understand why didn't Chrome automatically run the 3D software rasterizer as replacement for this black listed GPU/driver ?